# Hiding a Sub Directory in URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, routes

Inside `public_html` directory I have a folder `myfolder` and I have the `index.php` in that folder.

All my site url reads

```
http://example.com/myfolder/page-name
```

I want it to rewritten as

```
http://example.com/page-name
```

What rule should I write in `.htaccess` to achieve the same

Comment: Would someone please tell us if the answer is correct ???

Comment: I used @Jon Lin answer but not works for me.

Answer (score 4):

In your `public_html` directory's `.htaccess` file, add these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myfolder
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)$ /myfolder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This also seems to do the opposite for me, it adds a subdirectory where I want one removed.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /?myfolder/(.*) $1 [QSA,L]
```

The following sample does this: if we try to access something that doesn't start by `/myfolder`, then add `/myfolder` into the URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myfolder
RewriteRule (.*) /myfolder/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: One edit (at least for me) add a '/' after the second myfolder. It should be RewriteRule(.*) /myfolder/$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: This seems to do the opposite for me, it adds a subdirectory where I want one removed.

Comment: You're right. I've updated my answer but my #1 answer did reply to your question. Maybe your question isn't clear enough.